# missing many-to-one associations in OData Feed (olingo)

Tags: java, jpa, odata, many-to-one, olingo

I built a OData Producer based on apache olingo, JPA and mySQL following [this tutorial](http://scn.sap.com/community/netweaver-gateway/blog/2014/02/05/odata-producer-using-apache-olingo-with-mysql-jpa-tomcat-web-server)
While many-to-many associations are displayed within the OData Feed, many-to-one associations are not displayed at all (neither are their JOIN-columns visible)

Does anyone have an idea, how to get olingo to display those Associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2.0.0 [http://olingo.apache.org/download.html] release of Olingo V2 lib, it is not mandatory to annotate the relationship property with both name and referencedColumnName.

Refer to the JIRA issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-127 for more details.

Regards
Chandan

Comment: Great! I haven't seen that new release yet. But now Olingo throws a `NullpointerException` upon an eclipse generated JPA. I need to investigate this in detail. When it works, I'll give you an accepted answer checkmark

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem. Turns out olingo wasn't getting the default referencedColumnName correctly, so we had to set it manually on all our associations.

e.g.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)    
@JoinColumn(name="AccountId")
public Account account;
```

Becomes

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)    
@JoinColumn(name="AccountId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
public Account account;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately the associations still won't show up. They are not visible in the $metadata either... do you have any more ideas? ;)

Comment: One other problem we had was olingo gave the relationships strange names, so we had to disable the olingo name generation with `ODataJPAContext.setDefaultNaming(false)` in `initializeODataJPAContext`. Other than that it worked well for us so I can't help more sorry :(